# How to select data from table A but if some data is present in table B show its too into the result

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

i have some tables like this:

[image]

i want to select data from tbl_absensi but some data is present in tbl_setting_pmk 
can you help me, how to do this?

this is my Query :

[image]

but the data from sp.* isn't present in the result.

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing us what output you actually want, it is not clear from what you have shown us.

Comment: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You want an outer join (usually left join).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have add my query..

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Become like this : [![Capture.png](https://s14.postimg.org/8ru334rn5/Capture.png)]

Comment: It isn't clear to me why `Ucup Bahrudin` is being excluded from the result set.  Can you update your question with _clear_ business logic so that someone may help you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because Ucup Bahrudin have a "tanggal" different.